# Fujitsu LH532 touchpad detected as PS/2 Generic Mouse

Tags: 13.10, mouse, touchpad

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE                   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                         id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02B1                           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera                                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

I wish I could give better information, but the best I've come up with is hitting Fn+F4 each time I boot into Linux.  This disables the trackpad.

Comment: How does this answer the question?